# Restrict woocommerce checkout on quantity base

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know this question has been asked so many times , but this is somewhat different.
What i am trying to do is restrict checkout for users , If quantity is between **1 & 50** 

Our store only deals , when quantity is more than 50 . But i have a option of ordering sample ( Only 1 sample) 
So i want to restrict checkout when quantity is between  1 & 50 that is more than 1 but less than 50.
For Example - 
PRODUCT-A can be purchased only in quantity 1 or more than 50 , but not between 1 & 50. 
This condition applies on all products.
No plugins fulfill this condition.
Thanks

Comment: You really need to include some code. This could be as simple as `if((order > 1) && (order < 50))` or it could be much more complicated. No idea since you did not include an example.

Comment: you can check now. i added the example

Comment: Sorry, the logic is clear, but you need a code example. You tagged `php` and `jquery` but where do you want to implement that logic (server or client side?)

Comment: So how is jQuery related?

Comment: [Min/Max Quantities](https://www.woothemes.com/products/minmax-quantities/) can't do that?

Comment: nope, if you set minimum to 1 , you can still add 2 ,3 , 4 quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some custom add to cart validation. Here's an example of using the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter. If the item fails a test, set the boolean `$passed` to false and add an error notice with `wc_add_notice()`.

```
function so_34655871_quantity_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations, $cart_item_data ) { 
    if ( $quantity > 1 && $quantity < 50 ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You must buy either 1 or more than 50.', 'your-textdomain' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_34655871_quantity_validation', 10, 6 );
```

The update cart validation is similar, but slightly different since the [`woocommerce_update_cart_validation`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2b967215500284d0700ce655abc2521098ea44b7/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L451) filter is passed different variables.

```
function so_34655871_update_cart_quantity_validation( $passed, $cart_item_key, $values, $quantity ) { 
    if ( $quantity > 1 && $quantity < 50 ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You must buy either 1 or more than 50.', 'your-textdomain' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_validation', 'so_34655871_update_cart_quantity_validation', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Hey Thanks very helpful , It works well on  product page , It shows the error if you try to proceed with <50 quantity. But there is quantity box on Cart page too. You can add 50 quantity from product page , then change it back to less than 50 on cart page . !

Comment: Then you also need to validate with `woocommerce_update_cart_validation`

Comment: With same function? sorry i dont know much about actions and filters.

Comment: The exact same function won't work, but something very similar should. Try the new code.

Comment: woocommerce_update_cart_validation , isnt working for me , nothing happens , no errors , I can still proceed to checkout. I have posted the code in my answer . " woocommerce_check_cart_items" creates issues for my other plugin. It would be better if i find a way with woocommerce_update_cart_validation.

Comment: Working , i forgot to change to woocommerce_update_cart_validation

Comment: You should catch me when I do copy/paste errors. ;) The `so_34655871_update_cart_quantity_validation()` function was never added to the `woocommerce_update_cart_validation` filter so of course it never fires. It is working for me now.

Comment: Yea thanks :) first i did copy paste too .  Thanks for your help !